# How to set css properties to element but not to innerhtml

Tags: html, css

I wonder if there is any way to set properties to an element but not its children.

E.g

```
<div>
<span>A child</span>
</div>
```

That the span child will not get affected.

So if I want to for example give the div a blur filter and don't want to affect the children of the element, how do I do it?

Comment: Depends on the properties you want to set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS is hierarchical; any attribute applied to a parent is automatically inherited by the child:

[image: Inheritance]

The only way to give a parent an attribute while simultaneously excluding the child is to additionally give the child an attribute that overrides the parent (with higher [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)):

[image: Override]

This is best done with the [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial_value) value (which 'resets') the value, though you can use any other value you like:

```css
div {
  color: red;
}

div > span {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<div>Parent
  <span>A child</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, and you can use
div > *
to get all the children!

Answer (score 1):

You could set the required property on the element you want to affect, then select the children of this element and unset the same property or give it a different value.

Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

you can  give separate classes to them and specify options separately in css.

Comment: Oh yes yes, sorry for that, I delete all code will leave only thing about separate classes

Comment: No problem at all, thanks for editing :)

Answer (score 0):

Not if you target the `div` (in this case) directly, then the `span` is force-blurred as well.

But, you could fake the div with a [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements), perhaps something like this:

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

/* A fake box with the same dimensions as the div */
div::before {
    content: "";
    background: red;
    display: block;
    filter: blur(10px);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

span {
    position: relative; /* Z-index purposes */
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>I'm not blurry :D</span>
</div>
```